# Do turtlebot_bringup and turtlebot_dashboard need the same ROS version?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to have my Retina MBP (which won't support Ubuntu 13.04 due to hardware incompatibilities, so I'm stuck with 14.04) communicate with my custom turtlebot, running XUbuntu 13.04 on an Odroid U3 (through [UbuntuARM](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/UbuntuARM)). Essentially, my laptop can only run ROS Indigo and my turtlebot can only run ROS Hydro.

When I try to use the Turtlebot Dashboard, I get a slew of errors about incorrect message types. Has anyone had success running the Turtlebot software across two different versions of ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189624/do-turtlebot_bringup-and-turtlebot_dashboard-need-the-same-ros-version?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2014-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While many things are compatible between indigo and hydro, it seems in particular [anything with dashboards is problematic](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#diagnostic_msgs).

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2014-08-10**:
Great answer. Thanks!